# ExtJS 4.0.7 - Vertical scrollbar is not displayed/working in grid

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs-grid

I am new to `ExtJS`. I have a `grid` with add and delete button to add/delete rows. When rows exceeds the height of `grid`, I want to display a vertical scrollbar to this `grid`.

I have checked with configuring 'autoscroll : true' and 'scroll : true' to `grid` and its column also, but both these configuration are not displaying the vertical scrollbar.

Please help me to find the solution.
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: provide your code as what you have tried ?

Comment: set the layout property to fit for the container or panel in which your grid panel is..
this might add the auto scroll

Comment: I think you are writing it wrong as `autoscroll: true`, it should be `autoScroll: true`. [Reference](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-autoScroll)